# Can you create a grouping based on ranges?

Tags: linq, grouping

This is related to [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331678/how-to-create-a-grouping-listview-based-on-fuzzy-grouping), which I think really gets at a much simpler problem so I'm asking the simpler question here in the hopes it will help me solve the more complex one.

I would like to be able to create a grouping in a linq to sql query that groups based on a range of data within another set of data.  However, i think it should work just as well in linq to objects, so let's just go with that.

Imagine you have two lists containing values

```
{100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170}
{115, 145, 180}
```

Now, I would like to group the first list by the second as ranges (values that are between each group).  That is, I would like a grouping like this (the 0 is implied):

```
{0}   {100, 110}
{115} {120, 130, 140}
{145} {150, 160, 170}
{180}
```

I'm almost certain i'm misusing terminology, and probably have a misunderstanding of how linq group by operator works, but if you get what I mean, I'd love some suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can certainly *express* it in LINQ easily:

```
var x = from value in values
        group value by ranges.Where(x => value >= x)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
                             .Last();
```

But I very much doubt that that will work in LINQ to SQL. Basically you've got to find a simple way of mapping a value to one of those categories.

Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] values = {100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170};
        int[] ranges = {115, 145, 180};

        var query = from value in values
                    group value by ranges.Where(x => value >= x)
                                         .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         .Last();

        foreach (var group in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {{{1}}}", group.Key, 
                              string.Join(", ", group));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0: {100, 110}
115: {120, 130, 140}
145: {150, 160, 170}
```

Note that this *won't* include any categories which don't have any values in.

Also note that this would be simpler (using `First()` instead of `Last()`) if you'd be happy to categorize slightly differently:

```
115: {100, 110}
145: {120, 130, 140}
180: {150, 160, 170}
```

In other words, if the category was defined by the first range value *higher* than the row value.

EDIT: Here's a version which gives the empty groups. It's pretty horrible though, IMO:

```
var query = from range in ranges
            join value in values
            on range equals ranges.Where(x => value >= x)
                                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  .Last() into groups
            select new { Key = range, Values = groups};

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {{{1}}}", group.Key, 
                      string.Join(", ", group.Values));
}
```

Comment: I need the categories without values as well, but maybe i can figure something out there.  Your knowledge on these topics never ceases to amaze me ;)

Comment: Can't you just do an outer join to get the unused categories?

Comment: @Gabe: Outer joins aren't easy in LINQ. It's possible that a group join will work, but it's a bit of a pain... I'm having a look now.

Comment: Yeah, wow.. There has to be a better way to do this.. perhaps linq isn't the right tool.

Comment: If you don't like the outer join, you could always turn the original query into a dictionary, then iterate over the ranges and add in any range that's not represented.